# Media Query support in Outlook app using E-mail template

Tags: javascript, html, css, email-templates

Is there any way to support Media Query inside email template for Outlook App.

I want to hide and show the div in mobile view. If no then is there any way to support using JavaScript?

Comment: https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/

Comment: @anu check the most recent blog post from Litmus to know what is happening. Outlook.com app has started supporting media queries.

Comment: oki . Thanks for the info

Comment: @rakesh, was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: @Syfer i updated the app in android but still no solution. as well IOS outlook app support media query. i read the litmus blog but no result.
BTW thanx for answer all :)

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with your code? All old Outlook app reads media queries on _non Microsoft accounts_. **IF** you need help in media queries then you will need to ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Media query support is there for outlook.com app. You can read more about it [here](https://litmus.com/blog/consistent-media-query-support-returning-to-outlook-apps).

A basic breakdown from the article above is:

**Supported clients**

- Outlook iOS app
- Outlook Android app

**Supported account types**

- All (outlook.com, gmail.com, yahoo.com, aol.com, etc.)

**Supported mediatypes**

- all
- screen
- handheld

**Supported queries**

- min-width
- max-width
- min-device-width
- max-device-width
- orientation
- min-resolution
- max-resolution
- min-device-pixel-ratio

**Supported keywords**

- and
- only

If you have an older version of outlook.com app then media query support will be in only those email clients that are not from Exchange servers. Other email IPS will work on outlook.com app like Yahoo, Gmail etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: some of property still not support.

Comment: yes @syfer but still outlook window app is not support some media query.

Comment: The best way to do it so far is hybrid until media queries 'fully' come to Outlook apps. I noted above which ones are supported.

Comment: BTW thank you so much @Syfer for help me . really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Update your code in your original post with what you have tried. If I find anything I will update my post.